# timer starts automatically instead of on a button press in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript so the answer is probably quite easy but anyways

I'm trying to make a simple click speed test but i cant get the timer to start when the user presses the click me button, so i resorted to just starting it automatically. if anyone can help me to start it on the button press it will be much appreciated

HTML code:

```
<button id="click2" onclick="click2()">Click Me!</button><br>
<span id="clicksamount">0 Clicks</span><br><br>
<span id="10stimer">10s</span>
```

JS code:

```
var click = document.getElementById("click2");
var amount = 0;

var seconds = 10;
var endOfTimer = setInterval(click2, 1000);

function click2() {
    seconds--;
    document.getElementById("10stimer").innerHTML = seconds + "s";
    if (seconds <= 0) {
        var cps = Number(amount) / 10;
        document.getElementById("clicksamount").innerHTML = "You got " + cps + " CPS!";
        document.getElementById("click2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("10stimer").innerHTML = "Ended";
        clearInterval(seconds);
    }
}
document.getElementById("click2").onclick = function() {
    amount++;
    document.getElementById("clicksamount").innerHTML = amount + " Clicks";
}
```

Comment: Just move the `setInterval(click2, 1000);` to the onclick function

Comment: That'll keep creating a nwe interval each time they click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're overwriting your onclick function on the button with id `click2` with the lowest 4 lines.

Also, you call `clearInterval()` with the seconds variable instead of the actual interval, which is referenced by `endOfTimer`.

I'd suggest to have a separated timer management in a function which you call only on the first click of your button.

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/florianmuellerCH/L7ugna6z/)

```
<button id="clickbutton" onclick="buttonClick()">Click Me!</button><br>
<span id="clicksamount">0 Clicks</span><br><br>
<span id="secondcount">10s</span>
```

```
// We will have timerStarted to see if the timer was started once, 
// regardless if it's still running or has already ended. Otherwise
// we would directly restart the timer with another click after the 
// previous timer has ended.
// timerRunning only indicates wether the timer is currently running or not.
var timerStarted = false;
var timerRunning = false;
var seconds = 10;
var clickAmount = 0;
var timer;

function buttonClick() {
  if (!timerStarted) {
    startTimer();
  }
  // Only count up while the timer is running.
  // The button is being disabled at the end, therefore this logic is only nice-to-have.
  if (timerRunning) {
    clickAmount++;
    document.getElementById("clicksamount").innerHTML = clickAmount + " Clicks";
  }
}

function startTimer() {
  timerStarted = true;
  timerRunning = true;
  timer = setInterval(timerTick,1000);
}

function timerTick() {
  seconds--;
  document.getElementById("secondcount").innerHTML = seconds + "s";
  if (seconds <= 0) {
    timerRunning = false;
    clearInterval(timer);
    var cps = Number(clickAmount) / 10;
    document.getElementById("clickbutton").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("clicksamount").innerHTML = "You got " + cps + " CPS (" + clickAmount + "clicks in total)!";
  }
}
```

Comment: I rewrote the same way :P

Comment: you beat me by seconds :)

Comment: @sumit I'm not that often on SO and seldomly writing answers but this time I knew I could help and bring benefit for once :-D

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code. Effectively, when the user clicks the first time, you start the timer then. The timer variables is null until the first the user clicks.

```
var click = document.getElementById("click2");
var noOfClicks = 0;
var seconds = 10;
var timer  = null;

function doTick(){
  seconds--;
  if(seconds<=0){
    seconds = 10;
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("10stimer").innerHTML= "Ended"
    timer=null;
    document.getElementById("click2").disabled = true;

  }
  updateDisplay()
}

function updateClicks(){
if(!timer){
  timer=setInterval(doTick, 1000);
  clicks= 0;
  seconds = 10;

}
  noOfClicks++;

  updateDisplay();
}

function updateDisplay(){
      var cps = Number(noOfClicks) / 10;

      document.getElementById("clicksamount").innerHTML = "You got " + cps + " CPS!";
    document.getElementById("10stimer").innerHTML =seconds;


}
click.addEventListener('click', updateClicks)
```

https://jsbin.com/bibuzadasu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

```
function timer(startEvent, stopEvent) {
    let time = 0;
    startEvent.target.addEventListener(startEvent.type, () => {
        this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
            time++;
        }, 10); // every 10 ms... aka 0.01s

        removeEventListener(startEvent.type, startEvent.target); // remove the listener once we're done with it.

        stopEvent.target.addEventListener(startEvent.type, () => {
            clearInterval(this.interval); // stop the timer

            // your output function here, example:
            alert(time);

            removeEventListener(stopEvent.type, stopEvent.target); // remove the listener once we're done with it.
        });
    });

}
```

Use event listeners rather than onclicks

usage example:

> HTML

```
<button id="mybutton">Click me!</button>
```

> JS

```
/* ABOVE CODE ... */
let mybutton = document.getElementById("mybutton");
timer(
    {target: mybutton, type: "click"},
    {target: mybutton, type: "click"}
);
```

```js
function timer(startEvent, stopEvent) {
     let time = 0;
     startEvent.target.addEventListener(startEvent.type, () => {
      this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
       time++;
      }, 10); // every 10 ms... aka 0.01s

      removeEventListener(startEvent.type, startEvent.target); // remove the listener once we're done with it.

      stopEvent.target.addEventListener(startEvent.type, () => {
       clearInterval(this.interval); // stop the timer

       // your output function here, example:
       alert(time);
   
       removeEventListener(stopEvent.type, stopEvent.target); // remove the listener once we're done with it.
      });
        });
 
    }

    let mybutton = document.getElementById("mybutton");
    timer(
        {target: mybutton, type: "click"},
        {target: mybutton, type: "click"}
    );
```

```html
<button id="mybutton">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//state initialization
var amount = 0;
var seconds = 10;
var timedOut=false;
var  timerId=-1;
//counters display
var clicksDisplay= document.getElementById("clicksamount");
var timerDisplay= document.getElementById("10stimer");
function click2(e){
  //first click 
  if(timerId===-1){
      //start timer  
     timed();
  }
  //still in time to count clicks
 if(!timedOut){
    amount++;
  clicksDisplay.innerText=amount +" Clicks";
 }

}
function timed(){
  //refresh timer dispaly
   timerDisplay.innerText=seconds+"s";
  seconds--;

  if(seconds<0){
    //stop click count
    timedOut=true;    
  }else{
    //new timerId
  timerId=setTimeout(timed,1000);
  }
}
```